# Google Local Services API + CRM - Nested Arrays ( API Response Mapping )

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-ads-api, zapier, array-map

I’m building a custom Zap to integrate [Google Local Service Ads API](https://services.google.com/fh/files/helpcenter/lsa_api_dev_guide.pdf) with our CRM. It appears everything is functioning properly however, I noticed several new leads are not coming through, which appears to be due to the API request sending nested data using the  values nested under the same field .

Here is an example response:

```
    {
    "leadId": "000000000",
    "accountId": "000000000",
    "businessName": "Acme, Inc",
    "leadCreationTimestamp": "2022-08-09T16:21:14Z",
    "leadType": "PHONE_CALL",
    "leadCategory": "roofer",
    "geo": "Miami,Florida,United States",
    "phoneLead": {
      "consumerPhoneNumber": "+15555555678"
    },
    "chargeStatus": "NOT_CHARGED",
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "timezone": {
      "id": "America/New_York"
    },
    "id": "0000000000"
  },
  {
    "leadId": "000000000",
    "accountId": "000000000",
    "businessName": "Acme, Inc",
    "leadCreationTimestamp": "2022-08-09T16:39:38Z",
    "leadType": "MESSAGE",
    "leadCategory": "roofer",
    "geo": "Miami,Florida,United States",
    "messageLead": {
      "customerName": "Jane Doe",
      "jobType": "attic_venting",
      "postalCode": "33066",
      "consumerPhoneNumber": "+15555555789"
    },
    "chargeStatus": "CHARGED",
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "timezone": {
      "id": "America/New_York"
    },
    "id": "1111111111"
  },
  {
    "leadId": "000000000",
    "accountId": "000000000",
    "businessName": "Acme, Inc",
    "leadCreationTimestamp": "2022-08-10T19:12:28Z",
    "leadType": "PHONE_CALL",
    "leadCategory": "window_repair",
    "geo": "Miami,Florida,United States",
    "phoneLead": {
      "chargedCallTimestamp": "2022-08-10T19:12:28Z",
      "chargedConnectedCallDurationSeconds": "280s",
      "consumerPhoneNumber": "+15555555890"
    },
    "chargeStatus": "CHARGED",
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "timezone": {
      "id": "America/New_York"
    },
    "id": "2222222222"
  },
```

The issue I’m running into is when mapping the data to our CRM, the trigger test data is providing multiple fields for ‘consumerPhoneNumber’ ( based on whether it is a message/phone lead and whether the call connected ). so we are unable to map phoneLead__consumerPhoneNumber and messageLead___consumerPhoneNumber to the same field.

[duplicate fields example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjEpf.png)

How can I parse the API response to properly map the consumerPhoneNumber when the value changes based on messageLead_consumerPhoneNumber versus phoneLead_consumerPhoneNumber?

I understand some basic Javascript but parsing API data is new to me. Any help would be truly appreciated!

Here is the JavaScript code for our API request.

```
    const options = {
  url: 'https://localservices.googleapis.com/v1/detailedLeadReports:search',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bundle.authData.access_token}`,
    'X-QUERY': bundle.authData.query
  },
  params: {
    'query': 'manager_customer_id:XXXXXXXXX',
    'pageSize': '1000'

  }
}

return z.request(options).then((response) => {
  response.throwForStatus();
  const results = response.json;

  const lists = results["detailedLeadReports"].map((item) => {
    return Object.assign(item, {
      id: item["leadId"],
    });
  });

  return lists;
});
```